# System spiking CPU usage (causing 6000+ rpm on fans)

Tags: macos, performance, cpu

Im running a mid-2012 macbook pro on 10.9.5.

I've been having massive lag spikes over the last few weeks which have gotten more consistent and prevalent the last day. I have been wearing this macbook out for a while but these lag spikes are like nothing I have seen before.

[image: CPU Spikes that have happened while writing this post]

These are the spikes that have happened during the writing of this post. The system seems to take up to 80% of my cpu for differing lengths of time with no clear intervals.

Any tips on solving this or limiting the damage?
I have been thinking of updating this machine to 10.11.1 for a while to make it compatible with my Wacom pad, but now I'm questioning if my old friend could still handle this...

EDIT1:
The spikes have just started again and I have managed to capture the entire screen this time. Interesting to note is that as you can see I am running the steelseries engine for my mouse. During spikes my mouse completely ticks off as well and gets super sensitive until the end of the spike.

[image: Completeshot]

I hope this shines a bit more light onto the situation. Having trouble with my wifi TimeMachine backup at home so buying an external harddrive for backups soon after which i'll try to clean the insides to see if that helps any!

EDIT2:
Used the sudo syscallbypid.d command. These were the top results:
Try 1:

[image: TRY1]

Try 2 (Noticed hamachi taking alot of space so deleted that anyways):

[image: TRY2]

EDIT3:Tried it again, this time while not running chrome. Got another spike with these results:

[image: TRY3]

EDIT4(Still going): I've closed spotify and decided to see what happens then, still kept spiking. Was working with only pages open on a paper, first time with syscallbypid.d showed only pages taking up some space, but second time and third with some spikes later other stuff started to show up. Any idea what this could be?

[image: Try5]

[image: TRY4]

EDIT5: I've captured another screenshot of the entire screen from activity monitor to show what has been eating up most of the CPU, which is the Kernal_task. This spike happened with no other programs open, only stuff running in the background.

[image: Activitymonitor]

Comment: You need to check in the same window what precisely is eating all that CPU - if it's kernel_task, then it may be doing it simply to cool the machine, which may imply the hardware needs cleaning

Comment: Could you also post a screen shot of the individual CPU consumers, at least the op 10. This one does not show who is doing it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 updated the post with some more information, hope this might help some... Really appreciating the help!

Comment: Thank you, as you can see it is your Kernel tasks (the OS X) been very busy with something. Lets try to find out what is it.

Comment: Open Terminal and paste this `sudo syscallbypid.d` enter your password, let it run for a minute (it wont stop by it self)  then hold `control` + press `c`, now look on the right for the highest number and take screen shot of some of those and report in your original post.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Had some spikes and recorded during them, results are in the post!

Comment: Try a Malwarebytes and DetectX scan. You never know.

Comment: Quit Chrome and observe

Comment: @Buscar웃 Quit chrome and let it run for a while till I encountered another set of spikes. Results in the post!

Comment: thank you, so now we can see better in the jungle that your `Spotify` been very busy and accessing Network. Guess what ? :) tun it off.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Tried with spotify closed for a day but still kept getting small spikes. Turned syscallbypid.d on to check after some major ones and saw some other weird stuff popping up. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: are yo saying the spikes are now smaller ? can you just watch the Activity Monitor to see which app creates high CPU usage momentarily

Comment: @Buscar웃 When I said major ones, what I meant were longer spikes. 2 weeks ago the spikes were only a few seconds long at best. Now tho, they average up to two minutes or keep up while watching something through VLC. I've captured the start of a spike on the last screenshot, the "low" regular you see on the y axis is cpu usage between the 2% and 10%, while the spikes range from 70 to 80% usage...
EDIT: The spikes also come up more often with pauses between them ranging from 10 minutes to only a few seconds. Would the worsening over time be a clue to the origins?

Answer (score 1):

The chart representing the CPU usage in the Activity Monitor can be misleading.

The scale on the Y -axis is not 100% but changes according to the CPU usage.

You could see what it looks like spikes even if they are of extermly low magnitude.

See my example. It looks like spikes while the actual CPU consumption is low. In this case the User- CPU load is 0% to 5.93% and the chart Y-axis is set to 6% so it just looks like huge spikes.

[image: cpu]